# I'm having trouble getting data from razor page

Tags: razor, foreach, model

I have a controller where i call a page with a data model.

> ```
>         //** Get all members
>         IEnumerable<mdMedlemmer> medlemsModels = _medlemmer.GetAll(_options.LoggedInGuid.ToString());
>
>         //** Get listing result
>         var ListingResult = medlemsModels.Select(result => new MedlemsIndexListingModel
>         {
>             Id = result.ID,
>             Navn = result.Navn,
>             LicensNummer = result.LicensNummer,
>             Niveau = result.Niveau
>         }).OrderBy(o => o.Navn);
>
>         //** Set model
>         var model = new MedlemsIndexModel
>         {
>             Medlems = ListingResult
>         };
>
>         //** Show view with model
>         return View(model);
> ```

In my cshtml page i have this code:

```html
@model MinDartklub.Models.Medlemmer.MedlemsIndexModel

<table class="table table-condensed" id="medlemsIndexTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Navn</th>
            <th>Vælg</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Pujle", "Turnering", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            int counter = 1;
            @foreach (var medlems in Model.Medlems)
            {
                <tr class="medlemsRow">
                    <td class=""><input type="text" navn="txtSpiller_@counter" id="txtSpiller_@counter" value="@medlems.Navn" disabled/></td>
                    <td class=""><input type="checkbox" name="cbSpiller_@counter" /></td>
                </tr>
                counter++;
            }
                <tr class="medlemsRow">
                    <td class="" colspan="2"><input class="btn btn-lg btn-info" type="submit" value="Start pulje" /></td>
                </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Back in the controller i try to read the data:

```html
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Pujle(string txtSpiller_1, string cbSpiller_1)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Turnering");
        }
```

The cshtml pagge shows all the members and a checkbox

In the controller Start() method I want to read all the members who have been checked.
Any idea on how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found out I could use Request.Form.ToList()
This gives me a list of the member where I clicked in the checkbox.